# Convert VARCHAR(max) column to uppercase then to XML in a single query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried searching in StackOverflow with no success.

I would like to perform following two conversions on a `VARCHAR(max)` column, but in one query. This is T-SQL.

1. Convert all text in column to uppercase with `UPPER()` function
2. Convert column to `XML` datatype by using `CAST(column AS XML)` function

I tried below and is syntactically incorrect.

```
SELECT CAST(UPPER(inputText) AS XML) AS ConvertedText 
FROM SampleTable
```

Error returned by SSMS. (When I remove UPPER() the query runs without error.)

> namespaces beginning with "xml" are reserved

Comment: This works fine `SELECT CAST(UPPER('inputText') AS XML) AS ConvertedText` - what **exactly** and **in full** is the error message? (always include the error message if you are referring to an error)

Comment: Updated question to include error message

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is strictly case-sensitive. It is always dangerous to deal with XML with string-methods. Because XML is not just *a string with some fancy extras*...

Your XML is - I take this from the posted error message - including a *xml-declaration*. And additionally I'll speak about namespaces. XML is expecting the *xml-declaration* and declaration of namespace in *lower-case*. This cannot be upper-cased.

Check this out: I define a XML with a declaration, a default namespace and one more prefixed namespace.

```
DECLARE @testXML NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
  <root xmlns="dummy.default" xmlns:blah="Some.blah.namespace">
    <test a="attribute value">element value</test>
    <blah:NamespacedElement>value in a namespaced element</blah:NamespacedElement>
  </root>';

SELECT UPPER(@testXML);
/*
  <?XML VERSION="1" ENCODING="UTF-16"?>
  <ROOT XMLNS="DUMMY.DEFAULT" XMLNS:BLAH="SOME.BLAH.NAMESPACE">
    <TEST A="ATTRIBUTE VALUE">ELEMENT VALUE</TEST>
    <BLAH:NAMESPACEDELEMENT>VALUE IN A NAMESPACED ELEMENT</BLAH:NAMESPACEDELEMENT>
  </ROOT>
*/
```

--The declaration is broken as all internal content is expected to be lower-case. But this is easy. We can cut it away entirely. Within SQL-Server there is no sense in this declaration. It will be omited in any case...
--Secondly we have to deal with the `xmlns`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(UPPER(@testXML),'xmlns','xmlns'),PATINDEX('%?>%',@testXML)+2,1000000);
/*
  <ROOT xmlns="DUMMY.DEFAULT" xmlns:BLAH="SOME.BLAH.NAMESPACE">
    <TEST A="ATTRIBUTE VALUE">ELEMENT VALUE</TEST>
    <BLAH:NAMESPACEDELEMENT>VALUE IN A NAMESPACED ELEMENT</BLAH:NAMESPACEDELEMENT>
  </ROOT>
*/
```

--You can see, that the declaration is gone and the `xmlns` is lower-case now. And this can be casted to XML:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(UPPER(@testXML),'xmlns','xmlns'),PATINDEX('%?>%',@testXML)+2,1000000) AS XML)
```

But - to be honest - if this is not just a weird homework thing, you should never change the casing of XML for the *whole thing* (including the mark-up).

Comment: You were absolutely correct. The xml declaration was throwing the error when converted to upper case. Tragically, I was handed this xml text column with mixed casing in the elements, so I have no choice until a permanent solution can be performed. Excellent explanation!